# Where can the Delphi version of the Windows.Graphics.Capture API be downloaded?

Tags: windows, delphi, graphics, capture

Google Bard is convinced that the Delphi version of the Windows.Graphics.Capture API can be accessed as shown below:

> You can download the Delphi version of the Windows.Graphics.Capture API from the Embarcadero website at the following URL: "https://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/delphi/"

The URL does not exist.

BARD also claims the following URL is also a download source:

> You can download Windows.Graphics.Capture.pas for Delphi from the following website:
> Code snippet
> "https://github.com/Embarcadero/Delphi/tree/master/encapsulations/Windows.Graphics.Capture"

Again, doesn't seem to be a valid URL path.

Supposedly, the Windows.Graphics.Capture API is part of later versions of Delphi.

I just installed the Alexandria 11.3 trial version and the unit doesn't appear to be included.

Does anybody know of a valid source?

BARD seems a bit delusional about this issue, and regular Google search is coming up empty.

Comment: Welcome to AI - [Bard/ChatGTP making things up](https://www.google.ca/search?q=(Bard+|+ChatGPT)+making+things+up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

interfaces for the Classes exposed in [Windows.Graphics.Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture?view=winrt-22621) can be found in WinApi.GraphicsRT.pas, this unit is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\source\rtl\win\winrt

Comment: Thanks Damien. From now on I'll be trusting you more than Google BARD  :-)